# How can I install the Epel repository on 64-bit Fedora 17 machine?

Tags: fedora, repository

How can I install the Epel repository on 64-bit Fedora 17 machine?

I tried:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
```

and

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

but I get a error:

```
Retrieving http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
error: skipping http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm - transfer failed
```

Any clues?

Comment: `404` on both `download.fedoraproject.org`-URLs -- but this doesn't explain the `curl` error...

Comment: You don't need to. EPEL shouldn't contain anything not already present in Fedora's base repositories. What specific package are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a problem on their side, however EPEL is not needed for Fedora. [From their site](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#What_is_Extra_Packages_for_Enterprise_Linux_.28or_EPEL.29.3F):

> Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (or EPEL) is a Fedora Special Interest Group that creates, maintains, and manages a high quality set of additional packages for Enterprise Linux, including, but not limited to, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL),CentOS and Scientific Linux (SL).

Comment: Point for @Renan, besides his answer the current epel package is epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm the '6-5' seems gone from repos. If you find missing packages from Fedora's official repos, try rpmfusion.org.

Comment: The 6-7 dont works for me too. I'm having problems with the video card, so, maybe this repository could help me.

Comment: As pointed by @Renan "EPEL project provides add-on packages for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, 5, and 4 releases and compatible derivatives (e.g., CentOS)" ... read more at their FAQ: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ